# Desktop icon not executing bash

Tags: bash, icons

I've created a disktop icon to execute a bash command.  They both correct (the icon file and the bash file) as they do run individually.  But together, they do not work

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Backup Photos
Comment=Nothing
Exec=/home/guy/Applications/ftpsync-1.2.33/backupGuy.sh
Icon=
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;
StartupNotify=true
```

and my bash file is;

```
echo copie vers le nuage
./ftpsyncModifiedByGuy.pl -n ~/Images/photo ftp://backupuser:backuppassword@192.168.1.28/"guy_photos"
echo "copy vers l'ordinateur"
./ftpsyncModifiedByGuy.pl -n ftp://backupuser:backuppassword@192.168.1.28/"guy_photos" ~/Images/photo
```

Just to test the icon, I replaced the exec= line with the line from another desktop icon (android studio) and android studio starts.  Do the icon is set to execute properly.

The bash file is also set to allow execute. And it does run when I execute it directly in a terminal.

When I double click on the desktop icon, I see nothing at all.  It doesn't do the backup.

What is wrong?

Comment: try "Exec=gnome-terminal  -- /home/guy/Applications/ftpsync-1.2.33/backupGuy.sh"

Comment: Are your files of the `.pl` files in the same folder as you run the `backupGuy.sh` file from?  If so, you might want to add a `cd /home/guy/Applications/ftpsync-1.2.33/` before those lines of the `.pl` files are called.

Comment: Or you can add a line that says `Path=/home/guy/Applications/ftpsync-1.2.33/` so that your script starts in that folder.

Comment: For documentation about desktop-files including `Path` field see https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html .

Comment: omg... I can't beleive that I didn't think of that by myself. I've done thousands of batch files in Windows.  I think I was only thinking about the desktop icon and forgetting about the path.  Thanks. it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I just included the full path in the bash file like this

```
echo copie vers le nuage
/home/guy/Applications/ftpsync-1.2.33/ftpsyncModifiedByGuy.pl -n ~/Images/photo ftp://backupuser:backuppassword@192.168.1.28/"guy_photos"
echo "copy vers l'ordinateur"
/home/guy/Applications/ftpsync-1.2.33/ftpsyncModifiedByGuy.pl -n ftp://backupuser:backuppassword@192.168.1.28/"guy_photos" ~/Images/photo
```